# App not installed error when uninstall and install app again

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

I generated release apk by following this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.15/signed-apk-android). For first time generated apk installed on android device successfully. but when i **uninstall and install this apk again** its showing error App not installed.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings -> Appliaction Manager and check if your application is showing in the list. Uninstall it properly for all users(if your mobile support multiple users). Then Try to install this again.

Comment: Its more looks like a phone issue. Kindly share your phone manufacturer and model.